# Как использовать PageIndicatorView?

Tags: android, library

Требуется реализовать функционал, который представлен в [этой (PageIndicatorView)](https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView) библиотеке. Документация, как по мне, довольно скудна - мало что понятно. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить или предоставить пример функционирующего кода?

*Возможно, существуют более популярные и простые библиотеки с подобным функционалом. Буду рад, если подскажите.*

Answer (score 0):

Могу показать простой пример.

Для начала вам нужна создать LinearLayout.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linear_indicator"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
   </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

потом вам нужно определить LinearLayout в вашем классе и создать новый метод.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addDotsIndicator(0);
}

private void addDotsIndicator(int position){
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_indicator);// определение LinearLayout   
    TextView[] mdots = new TextView[3];// добавление точек или кружочков
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();// очищает view при переходе точек. 

    for (int i = 0; i < mdots.length; i++){
        mdots[i] = new TextView(this);
        mdots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        mdots[i].setTextSize(46);
        mdots[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        linearLayout.addView(mdots[i]);
    }
    if (mdots.length > 0){
        mdots[position].setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Если вы используете ViewPager. Вам нужно наисать обработчик.

```
 private final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        addDotsIndicator(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

    }
};

mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListener);
```

Ну вот и все...

Comment: В данном случае, получается, выводятся только точки. Но, - вероятно, это не очень очевидно из вопроса, - задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать несколько панелей с разным содержанием, по которым можно переходить слайдом. Скажем, как `TabLayout`.

Comment: Для этого, кажется, нужно использовать ViewPager - он фигурирует в документации.

Comment: вам нужно поставить LinearLayout  в верх TabLayout и использовать ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, я там исправил свой ответь.